# Django serializers accessing multiple tables with ForeignKey Relationships

Tags: rest, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I have a requirement to build a social networking back-end using Django Rest framework, Where each user can see the Feeds from their Friends, which is stored in the Feeds-Table. I am currently using a view to generate the output.

here is my models.py

```
   from django.contrib.auth.models import User
   from django.db import models

   class Friends_list(models.Model):
         profile=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="user_name")
         friends=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="friends_name")
         accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
         date_of_follow = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

         def __str__(self):
            return self.profile.username


   class Feeds(models.Model):
         author=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='feed_creator')
         text=models.CharField(max_length=2000,blank=True)
         date_feed=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

         def __str__(self):
         return self.creator.username
```

and here is my views.py

```
 class Friends_feed(APIView):
     permissions_class = (IsAuthenticated,)

     def post(self,request):
         user_id=User.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('user_id'))
         friends_list=Friends_list.objects.filter(profile=user_id).values_list('friends',flat=True)
         feedlist={}
         for i in friends_list:
             uu=User.objects.get(id=i)
             friends_data=list(Feeds.objects.filter(author=uu).values_list('id','text','date_feed').order_by('-date_feed')[:1])
             friends_data.insert(0,uu.username)
             feedlist[uu.id]=friends_data
         return Response({'flist':feedlist})
```

and this is what my json Response is.

```
   {
    "flist": {
"1": [
  "sakshi",
  [
    4,
    "hey this is me sakshi",
    "2017-03-17T07:05:44.158641Z"
  ]
],
"9": [
  "vivekkk",
  [
    6,
    "my first post on bespal.... hurraay:",
    "2017-03-17T07:06:41.377392Z"
  ]
],
"15": [
  "levis",
  [
    7,
    "my seconf post",
    "2017-03-17T10:00:00.111989Z"
  ]
]
 }
 }
```

So i am confused if this is the right way of doing this, or is there a better way to do this using serializers in rest framework.

Any suggestions or corrections are appreciated and thanks in advance

**EDITS**

also i have tried some Serializer class where i could get the feeds of all users, but i cant filter the feeds of Friends, making use of Friends_list model.

serializers.py

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class Fserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
           model=Feeds
           fields=['text','date_feed']


    class Feedserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        feed_creator=Fserializer(many=True)
        class Meta:
           model=User
           fields=['username','feed_creator']
```

and views.py

```
   class Friends_feed(APIView):
       serializer_class=Feedserializer
       def post(self,request):
            serializer=Feedserializer(friendsquery,many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

here i am stuck where to apply the filters to get the friends of the users

Comment: DRF serializers is a better way

Comment: @Ykh can you suggest some ideas like what serializers should be used and where the friend filtering should be done.

Comment: change your friendlist from list to queryset

Answer (score 0):

you can use SerializerMethodField...like this....

> ```
> class Feedserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
>
>     field = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_field_detail')
>
>     def get_field_detail(self, obj):
>     '''you can apply your logic here to get required data'''
>
>     try:
>         obj = ClassName.objects.get(id=obj.movie.id)
>         bj_ser = ClassNameSerializer(obj)
>         return crmobj_ser.data
>     except:
>         return None
> ```

don't forget to include this field in meta class fields attribute
more on serializermethodfield [link](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield